# XPath. Determining the row of a scraped table

Tags: php, xpath

I am having a problem creating an INSERT statement using XPath.  Here is my table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="messagecellbody">row1 cell1</td>
    <td class="messagecellbody">row1 cell2</td>
    <td class="messagecellbody">row1 cell3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="messagecellbody">row2 cell1</td>
    <td class="messagecellbody">row2 cell2</td>
    <td class="messagecellbody">row2 cell3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And the output would ideally be this:

INSERT INTO database_table (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('row1 cell1', 'row1 cell2', 'row1 cell3');
INSERT INTO database_table (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('row2 cell1', 'row2 cell2', 'row2 cell3');

The code I am using is this:

```
$my_xpath_query = "//table//td[contains(@class, 'messagecellbody')]";
$result_rows = $xpath->query($my_xpath_query);

foreach ($result_rows as $result_object) {
    echo "'" . $result_object->nodeValue . "'";
}
```

This finds each  correctly, but output is the cell contents of all 6 cells.  I don't know how to break it on each row (so I can echo 'INSERT INTO database_table' etc.)

If I insert an extra parameter, I can filter it by column number e.g. the following will give me the first column

```
$my_xpath_query = "//table//td[contains(@class, 'messagecellbody')][1]";
```

but the problem remains of not knowing when the row ends and another one starts.  Without this, it is difficult to create my INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try instead getting the TR rows as individual objects in your Xpath search.  Are there any TR elements whose children you don't wish to include?

Then you would be able to get the child nodes of those objects (i.e. the TD elements you're looking for).

Something like:

```
$my_xpath_query = "//table//tr";
$result_rows = $xpath->query($my_xpath_query);

foreach ($result_rows as $result_object) {
    foreach($result_object->childNodes as $td) {
         echo "'" . $td->nodeValue . "'";
    }  
}
```

I haven't tested that - but I think something like that might solve your problem.

Comment: Of course!  Go up to the tr level instead of the td.  I was able to select the right table on the page and then exclude the first two rows that I didn't need using $my_xpath_query = "//table[contains(@class, 'bbstable')]//tr[position()>2]";  thank you!